# Have two LinearLayouts have equal height using layout_weight, not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having difficulty getting these two LinearLayouts nested in a single LinearLayout to have equal height. The first LinearLayout has 0 height while the second takes up the entire screen.

 Not sure if it's important but I programmatically populate the second LinearLayout with buttons.

**XML**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.yako.mimibot.pages.RemoteCtrlFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/remote_ctrl_ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/terminal_ll"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/terminal_window">
            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/terminal_scroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/terminal_rl"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </RelativeLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/remote_gesture_btns_ll"
            android:gravity="center">
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code For Populating Second LinLay (R.id.remote_gesture_btns_ll)**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remote_ctrl, container, false);

        mRemoteGestureBtnsLL = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.remote_gesture_btns_ll);
        mTerminalRL = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.terminal_rl);

        String[] mimiGestures = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mimi_capable_gestures_array);

        LinearLayout mimiBtnsLL = null;
        Button mimiBtn;
        for (int i=0; i < mimiGestures.length; i++) {
            if (i%2 == 0) {
                mimiBtnsLL = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
                mimiBtnsLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                mimiBtnsLL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                mimiBtnsLL.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            }

            mimiBtn = new Button(getActivity());
            mimiBtn.setText(mimiGestures[i]);
            mimiBtn.setHeight(100);
            mimiBtn.setWidth(200);
            mimiBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            mimiBtnsLL.addView(mimiBtn);

            if (i%2 == 1) {
                mRemoteGestureBtnsLL.addView(mimiBtnsLL);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your code to populate the second linear layout? and have you tried to change the root layout_height to match_parent?

Comment: Just tried setting the heights to match parent. Didnt help. Also uploaded the population code.

Comment: Why are you casting terminal_rl to RelativeLayout?

Comment: I've since added some more stuff inside the linear layout, ill update the XML.

Comment: Try setting the height of parent `LinearLayout` (with id `remote_ctrl_ll `) to `match_parent`.

Comment: @shhp It worked!!! You should add an answer so I can mark this question answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the height of parent `LinearLayout` (with id `remote_ctrl_ll` ) to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the weight & height explicitly on your first nested LinearLayout. try setting the height explicitly on your Root LinearLayout, and use ONLY layout_weights for the nested LinearLayouts

Comment: Im setting the height explicitly because its the only way I could see the content. Preferably I wouldnt want to set any height explicitly I want them to be split depending on the size of the screen. Can you post the xml for the fix?

Comment: what do you mean setting the height explicitly is the only way to see the content?

Comment: As in Im not giving it a value other than `MATCH_PARENT` or `WRAP_CONTENT` i.e. `300dp`. I updated the XML in my question by the way.